# Website losing query params when url is typed on broswer

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I type on my broswer *https://localhost/explore?name=teste* I get redirected to *https://localhost/explore*, it's seens to be losing the query params.

But when I click on my button, I'm redirected corretly to *https://localhost/explore?name=teste*.

**How can I stop it from losing it's query params?**

*Obs: When I navigate to Explore page, the page reloads a few times. At the first time, the query parameters (QP) are there, but on other reloads it loses the QP*

> The page that I want to open

```
export default function Explore() {

    const { query } = useRouter()
    const router = useRouter()

    const { data, error } = useSWR(url +"?"+ utils.objectToQueryString(query))

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <main className={styles.main}>

                <PlacesPanel places={data}/>

                <div className={styles.rightpanel}>
                    <MapSelector/>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> My button click

```
route.replace({
  url: "/explore",
  query: "name=teste",
  options: { shallow: true }
})
```

> My _app

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const customFetcher = (url) => api.get(url).then(r => r.data)

  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ fetcher: customFetcher }}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

> My folders structure

[image: Folder struture]

> The API fecther

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3001';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
});

export default api;
```

> My next.config.json

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["i.picsum.photos"],
},
}
```

If you need any additional information, I can provide it, I'm from mobile development these techs are new for me.

Comment: Do you have any data fetching methods (`getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps`/`getInitialProps`) in `explore` or `_app` pages? Also, do you have any `redirects` setup in your `next.config.json`?

Comment: Hey @juliomalves I don't have any of these fetching methods on _Explore_ or __app_, I just have the `useSWR`. And I updated my question with the _next.config.json_. I already tried to remove `useSWR` and use the `getServerSideProps` with `fetch`, but the query params get lost too.

Comment: Still not able to replicate the issue. I'm guessing whatever's making the page reload is the culprit for the query params getting removed, but none of the code you provided seems to be responsible for that. Would you be able to provide a codesanbox (or similar) with the issue?

Comment: I'll try to put my code on a codesandbox.

Comment: @juliomalves I figurated out my problem while I was moving my code to _codesandbox_... The problem was that I have a component `MapSelector`, to filter some places, inside the _Explore page_ and when I enter on the page, it has a `UseEffect`  inside de component that is removing the Query Params because my filter list is empty ¬¬..... I appreciate your help, thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the component `MapSelector`, which has an unecessary `useEffect` that I forgot to remove.

```
const MapSelector = () => {
  const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([]);

  const selectState = (initials) => {
    if (stateIsSelected(initials))
      setStateList(stateList.filter((item) => item !== initials));
    else setStateList([...stateList, initials]);
  };

  const buttonClick = () => {
    route.replace({
        url: "/explore",
        query: `name=test`,
        options: { shallow: true }
    })
  }

  // The problem...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stateList.length === 0) {
      route.replace({
          url: "/explore",
          query: "",
          options: { shallow: true }
      })
    } else {
      route.replace({
          url: "/explore",
          query: `name=test`,
          options: { shallow: true }
      })
    }
  }, [stateList]);


  [...]
}
```

I had moved the code to `buttonClick`, but I had forgotten to remove the `useEffect`... And when I enter on the *Explore page* this component is built and executes the `useEffect` cleaning the query params with the `route.replace`.